# Linking WASAPI in VS 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, audio, wasapi

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and have included these headers:

```
#include <Audioclient.h>
#include <mmdeviceapi.h>
```

Referencing, among others, these functions:

```
CoCreateInstance
IMMDeviceEnumerator::GetDefaultAudioEndpoint
IMMDevice::Activate
```

I've linked winmm.lib, but I'm getting errors like this:

```
Error   8   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator  C:\XXXX\XXXX\XXXX.obj   XXXX
```

What .lib file do I need to link to pick up these functions?  Is there any guidance on how to find the .lib associated with a .h file in VS 2010?

I'm looking at some [example code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316756%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from MSDN, but I can't find which library needs to be linked.

Comment: From [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowssdk/thread/a6101477-3e3d-4613-9605-e347ecd16b34/), `__uuidof()` should work.

Answer (score 7):

From Chris.  I Changed the code from this:

```
hr = CoCreateInstance(
    CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator, NULL,
    CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator,
    (void**)&pEnumerator);
```

To this:

```
hr = CoCreateInstance(
         __uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator), NULL,
         CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
         __uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator),
         (void**)&pEnumerator);
```

Now it links!

Comment: CLSCTX_ALL should actually be just fine.